# How to diagram a linear program flow that processes asynchronous output in UML?

Tags: asynchronous, uml, visualization, diagram, sequence-diagram

I'm working my way through programming some code which is connected to a console but reads from the log file. This is unique in that data is constantly being written to the log and I and I'm only able to examine it as I receive it. Data is received in packets which are assembled into "lines" and then I regex on each line to see if it's the data I'm looking for.

For example:

```
(output) -- ignore
(output) -- ignore
(output) -- ignore
(input ) -- > ask for A - enable regex for A
(output) -- ignore
(output) -- ignore
(output) -- regex match - A_START - enable regex for B and C
(output) -- regex match - B
(output) -- regex match - B
(output) -- regex match - B
(output) -- regex match - C
(output) -- regex match - A_END - process completed data set
```

Output is written to the log asynchronous from my application so I cannot send a command and then expect the next output to be the result; it will be output at some point in the future. Therefore my read buffer is usually only a single line.

Note that a matching line for `A` might appear at any time which is why I explicitly enable and disable these regex patterns as they are needed and in sequence.

This may seem impossible to parse but there is order to this madness. While data received is asynchronous, it is sent in "blocks" where each block is a complete data set. For example, if data set X, Y, Z is each a single line then it can appear in the log in any order. But if X is three lines then it will ALWAYS appear as three adjacent lines, regardless of its relative position to Y and Z.

This allows me to regex on a very explicit START of a block to know when to enable greedy regex, then at an explicit END regex of the block I know to disable the greedy regex.

At the end of the block I now have a complete data set.

While this is pretty easy to do once a good foundation of code has been written, the problem I'm having is that the code for what is actually a very linear read of some data is inherently non-linear as it appears in the source file due to having to jump between disparate regular expression triggers and additional callbacks.

What I want to do is diagram this as UML in detail so that I can refer to it again later on because I KNOW that I'm going to have a hell of a time making sense of it three months from now.

The actual procedure I'm doing write now is more complicated than the short example I have above. It is similar but for each entry `B` in `A` I have to send another command to pull an additional data set which is related to `A`. The complete data set for `A` isn't finished until I have everything.

Here is a BRIEF summary of the sequence:

```
> invoke catalog show

(output) -- Catalog Begin
(output) Collection 1
(output) Collection 2
(output) Collection 3
(output) -- Catalog End

// foreach next entry in Catalog...

> invoke Collection 1 show

(output) -- Collection Begin
(output) ...
(output) ...
(output) ...
(output) -- Collection End

// Perform action on Collection 1

// foreach next entry in Catalog...
```

And here is a more detailed summary of the same thing:

```
-- enable 'catalog begin' regex pattern

> invoke catalog show

(output) -- Catalog Begin
   -- REGEX MATCH
      -- disable 'catalog begin' regex pattern
      -- enable 'catalog entry' regex pattern

(output) Collection 1
-- REGEX MATCH
   -- add to catalog list
(output) Collection 2
-- REGEX MATCH
   -- add to catalog list
(output) Collection 3
-- REGEX MATCH
   -- add to catalog list

(output) -- Catalog End
   -- REGEX MATCH
      -- disable 'catalog end' regex pattern
      -- enable 'collection begin' regex pattern
      -- collections max = 3
      -- next collection = 1
      -- send command: invoke Collection 1 (next collection) show

> invoke Collection 1 show

(output) -- Collection Begin
   -- REGEX MATCH
      -- disable 'collection begin' regex pattern
      -- enable 'collection entry' regex pattern

(output) ...
-- REGEX MATCH
   -- add to collection entry list
(output) ...
-- REGEX MATCH
   -- add to collection entry list
(output) ...
-- REGEX MATCH
   -- add to collection entry list

(output) -- Collection End
   -- REGEX MATCH
      -- disable 'collection begin' regex pattern
      -- enable 'collection entry' regex pattern
      -- next collection + 1 (2)
      -- send command: invoke Collection 2 (next collection) show
      -- if next collection > 3 (collections max)... (false)

-- repeats for all 3 entries

> invoke Collection 2 show
...
-- collections invoked + 1 (3)
-- if next collection > 3 (collections max)... (false)

> invoke Collection 3 show
...
-- collections invoked + 1 (3)
-- if next collection > 3 (collections max)... (true)
-- perform processing on data (catalog list and collection lists)
```

Please help me understand how I can diagram this clearly so that I can understand how to assemble all of the various parts which make up an otherwise very linear operation.

### UPDATE:

I think this is the correct approach?

I have "Action" which is where I want to issue a command to request some information. There is the log file which is "Output" from the system and the "Display" which is the loop where I am reading each line as it is received from the output.

The output is asynchronous (in its own column) and the display is asynchronous from that as it only displays each line as it is read. And an action is also performed asynchronously (it can be invoked at any time).

I think this is the right approach. Now how do I join these three together to illustrate their relationship?

[image]

Comment: The design is already functional. What I lack is experience in how to express this kind of program flow in UML. I am looking for guidance on how to do this. What type of diagram, how to draw things in a way to communicate that this the output is asynchronous, etc. I've explained it in text form but I want to know if it can be presented more clearly as a diagram.

Comment: No time for a proper answer now, but I believe activity diagrams can do exactly what you want.

Comment: You suggest to create a diagram with three columns. Are these three actors working in parallel? In that case, I interpret 'Action' as the human actor (the user), 'Display' as the process reading from the log file and 'Output' as the external system writing information to the log file. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an activity diagram, a sequence diagram or a state machine diagram. All three diagram types have extensive possibilities to model asynchronous processes. For your purpose, I think an activity diagram is to be preferred. Using the "fork" symbol, you can create two parallel threads, each listening to different events. For listening to an event, use the appropriate polygon as shown in the diagram below. Threads may communicate using object flows (the orange arrows), optionally via a data store. I tried to create an activity diagram to reflect a part of your algorithm. The colors are not prescribed by UML. I have used colors to highlight the different kind of model elements.

[image: ad]

I hope this helps. Note, that the diagram does not have an end node. If the activity should stop under a certain condition, then you would have to add that. Furthermore, it waits for another block after each regexp match. You will have to extend the diagram to show that it applies multiple regexps to a single block.

Comment: The process I use to read the log is single-threaded. It has to be because each line of the log file has to be read sequentially. The addition of any threads wouldn't be applicable until after the entire block has been read, at which point there would no longer be any data to read from the log for that block. I also don't read any input. I can send input but this also happens in the same thread. The way to diagram this may actually be linear; I'm not yet certain what the correct approach will be. Thank you for this diagram but it does not appear to illustrate the procedure in my question.

Comment: When I read from the log it's basically just a line-by-line read in a loop. At some point I will enable a regex and then submit a command to request certain data to be displayed which cascades into several other regexps until a known "end" point is met which signals the end of a block.

Comment: Please try to draw the activity diagram as far as you can and show me which part you were unable to model.

Comment: you probably do not wanted to use *accept event actions*, else what are these links from the _merge_ to them  and why that _fork_ ?

Comment: @bruno, I thought it was needed to simultaneously wait for log data and wait for user input. That's why I created two threads. When either is received, it is processed and then the app waits for another event. But apparently, Zhro only needs one thread.

Comment: Well, I voted to close the question as (I think) the OP wants us to make his design. Or even worse, describe a broken design :-/

Comment: I've updated my question with an attempt at diagramming this. Where do I go from here?

Comment: @qwerty_so I didn't know where to start making a diagram for this or even which kind of diagram to use at the start of my question. It's going to take some time for me to understand this. I tried to describe the problem in detail to illustrate that I already have a concrete procedure in code and that it's the diagram specifically that I need help learning how to model.

Comment: Documenting in UML is mainly to get a grip of the design - and improving it. I think that this answer is a good design for your problem. You seem to insist of documenting a broken design (that's why it takes so long to describe it). Maybe you start thinking the whole thing over? If you try to get an answer to something here, make an effort to get to the point. Your question doesn't do that. You're just dumping all the issues you have.

Comment: @Zhro, thank you for your first attempt to draw a diagram. Let's take one step at a time. In a comment, you wrote: "When I read from the log, it's basically just a line-by-line read in a loop". I have captured this in one element called "Read block from log". Do you want to explicitly see the line-by-line-read as a loop in the diagram or would you be satisfied to summarize this in one element "Read block from log line by line"? Because your procedure is complex, maybe it would be better not to model this loop explicitly, in order to limit the size of the diagram. What do you think?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Would you explain what you mean by a broken design?

Comment: I didn't use those words. It was @qwerty_so  :-)

Comment: It was me talking about broken design. I tend to use Occam's Razor.

Comment: @qwerty_so Please don't label this a broken design without proposing an alternative approach. It is degrading an nonconstructive.

Comment: So: You have an excellent design here! Feel better now? Guess why nobody is giving you an answer except one kind soul.

Comment: @Zhro, if you still need help, please answer my last question (Jun 18, 6:49).